# How to convert ECDSA Public Key to PEM Files

Tags: go, cryptography, pem, ecdsa

I'm using the golang ecdsa package: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/ecdsa/

I have public key structs (https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/ecdsa/#PublicKey) and I'm trying to convert them to PEM files for use in other application.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Use [x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#MarshalPKIXPublicKey) and [the encoding/pem package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/pem/).

Answer (score -2):

You can check  this functions

https://github.com/gtank/cryptopasta/blob/master/marshal.go

That seems to be encoding using pem
Specially here

Using

```
import (
"crypto/ecdsa"
"crypto/x509"
"encoding/base64"
"encoding/pem"
"errors"
"fmt"
)




 // EncodePrivateKey encodes an ECDSA private key to PEM format.
  func EncodePrivateKey(key *ecdsa.PrivateKey) ([]byte, error) {
     derKey, err := x509.MarshalECPrivateKey(key)
          if err != nil {
             return nil, err
      }

    keyBlock := &pem.Block{
    Type:  "EC PRIVATE KEY",
    Bytes: derKey,
}

return pem.EncodeToMemory(keyBlock), nil
}
```

Comment: It's nice that you try and show code for the comment of Peter, but why then show the private key instead of the public key?